# Queue used as a pointer

Tags: c

I was coding for my uni exercise and currently we are learning about queues in C. This exercise is about queues realised with a list.

```
typedef struct cvor{ //elements of a list
    double broj; //number
    struct cvor *sljed; //pointer to next element
}cvor;

typedef struct red{ //queue realised with a list
    cvor *ulaz; //enter pointer
    cvor *izlaz; //exit pointer
}red;
```

I have two functions. Initialise queue and add element to queue:

```
void init_red(red *red);
int dodaj_u_red(double broj, red *red);
```

In my main function I first initialised variable red as a pointer, because of which my program didn't work at all. I debugged it and it crashed when it reached init_red(red). I can't wrap my head around why the code doesn't work if the queue is a pointer.

```
void init_red(red *red){
    red->ulaz = NULL;
    red->izlaz = NULL;
}

int dodaj_u_red(double broj, red *red){
   cvor *novi; //novi means new
   if( (novi = malloc(sizeof(cvor)))){ //checking for error

        novi->broj = broj;
        novi->sljed = NULL;

        if(red->izlaz == NULL) red->izlaz = novi;
        else (red->ulaz)->sljed = novi;

        red->ulaz = novi;

        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the main function is

```
int main(void){

    red red;  //if I change this is *red and I change argument parameters 
    double broj; //from &red to red the program doesn't work

    int n, i;
    printf("Upisite koliko brojeva zelite dodati u listu: ");
    do{
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(n > 10 || n < 0){
            printf("Pogresna velicina broja. Broj mora biti izmedu 1 i 10.");
        }
    }while(n > 10 || n < 0);

    init_red(&red);

    for( i = 0; i < n; i++){

        printf("Upisi %d clan: ", i+1);
        scanf("%lf", &broj);
        if( !(dodaj_u_red(broj, &red))) return 1;
        printf("Novi clan je: %lf.\n", (red.ulaz)->broj);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Version of main function which doesn't work. (crashes when reaches init_red(red) ; line)

```
int main(void){

    red *red; 
    double broj;

    int n, i;
    printf("Upisite koliko brojeva zelite dodati u listu: ");
    do{
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(n > 10 || n < 0){
            printf("Pogresna velicina broja. Broj mora biti izmedu 1 i 10.");
        }
    }while(n > 10 || n < 0);

    init_red(red);

    for( i = 0; i < n; i++){

        printf("Upisi %d clan: ", i+1);
        scanf("%lf", &broj);
        if( !(dodaj_u_red(broj, red))) return 1;
        printf("Novi clan je: %lf.\n", (red.ulaz)->broj);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: void init_red(red *red)  -- What is this?

Comment: @purec function for initialising the queue. It sets the list as null.

Comment: I mean you have type red and pointer variable also named red. Your compiler does not complain about it?

Comment: @purec not really. My college uses c90 standard for C-related courses.

Comment: "because of which my program didn't work at all"
Please be more specific. Compilation error?

Comment: Yes, you can do such things... funny.

Comment: Also, mention (maybe separately) what exactly you wrote in the 'red *red' line.

Comment: As a side note, you might want name your struct and object/pointer different in future programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't allocate any memory for *red.
Change that line to

```
red *red = (red*)malloc(sizeof(red));
```

Comment: I forgot to add line
    red *red = NULL;
I guess that is the problem because that doesn't allocate any memory and I need to allocate memory for init_red function?

Comment: Assigning NULL won't solve the problem. I would recommend you to make the change I suggested and try running.